# Google fit aggregate rest api call issue parse error javascript

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I am calling the google fit rest api as following

```
 const requestBody ={
    "aggregateBy": [{
      "dataTypeName": "com.google.step_count.delta",
      "dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps"
    }],
    "bucketByTime": { "durationMillis": 86400000 },
    "startTimeMillis": 1561228200000,
    "endTimeMillis": 1561652514300
    }

const userAction = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataset:aggregate', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: requestBody, 
      headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Content-Length': '302',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + authcode,
      }
    });
    const jsonResponse = await response.json();
    console.log(jsonResponse);
  }
  userAction();
```

I am getting response as

`{
    "error": {
        "errors": [{
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "parseError",
            "message": "Parse Error"
        }],
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Parse Error"
    }
}`

Not sure where the parsing error is happening. Any help pointing to where it occours will be much appreciated. 
Note - auth token is taken correctly, so it probably cant be the issue.
Also I am running on local host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work by the following code(I have hardcoded static params). Add api key and client ID and run it would work.
This link helped - https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/users/dataset/aggregate.

```js
<script>

  function authenticate() {
    return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
        .signIn({scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read"})
        .then(function() { console.log("Sign-in successful"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error signing in", err); });
  }
  function loadClient() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey("YOUR APP ID");
    return gapi.client.load("https://content.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/fitness/v1/rest")
        .then(function() { console.log("GAPI client loaded for API"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); });
  }
  // Make sure the client is loaded and sign-in is complete before calling this method.
  function execute() {
    return gapi.client.fitness.users.dataset.aggregate({
      "userId": "me",
      "resource": {
        "aggregateBy": [
          {
            "dataTypeName": "com.google.step_count.delta",
            "dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps"
          }
        ],
        "endTimeMillis": 1561652514300,// Any time in milliseconds
        "startTimeMillis": 1561228200000,// Any time in milliseconds
        "bucketByTime": {
          "durationMillis": 86400000// Any duration in milliseconds
        }
      }
    })
        .then(function(response) {
                // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
                console.log("Response", response);
              },
              function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
  }
  gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
    gapi.auth2.init({client_id: "YOUR CLIENT ID"});
  });
</script>
<button onclick="authenticate().then(loadClient)">authorize and load</button>
<button onclick="execute()">execute</button>
```